# Why as.data.frame() ignores row.names when converting a tibble

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

```r
library(tibble)
aa <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = letters[1:3])       #Data Frame
bb <- as_tibble(aa)                               #Tibble

#Conversion from Data Frame: Output dataframe has row names (As expected)
dd <- as.data.frame(aa, row.names = aa$y)       
attributes(dd)$row.names
## [1] "a" "b" "c"

#Conversion from Tibble: Output dataframe does not have row names (Problem)
ee <- as.data.frame(bb, row.names = bb$y)
attributes(ee)$row.names
## [1] 1 2 3

is.character(bb$y) #Confirmation that character vector was supplied
## [1] TRUE
```

Please note that the question is 'why there is a difference?'. I tried to look into more details as follows:

```r
library(sloop)
s3_dispatch(as.data.frame(bb, row.names = bb$y))  #Tibble to DataFrame
## => as.data.frame.tbl_df
##    as.data.frame.tbl
##  * as.data.frame.data.frame
##  * as.data.frame.default

s3_get_method(as.data.frame.tbl_df)
## function (x, row.names = NULL, optional = FALSE, ...) 
## {
##     class(x) <- tibble_class
##     unname <- which(!map_lgl(x, is_bare_list))
##     x[unname] <- map(.subset(x, unname), vectbl_set_names, NULL)
##     class(x) <- "data.frame"
##     x
## }
## <bytecode: 0x000001e57b5e3840>
## <environment: namespace:tibble>

s3_dispatch(as.data.frame(aa, row.names = aa$y))  #DataFrame to DataFrame
## => as.data.frame.data.frame
##  * as.data.frame.default

s3_get_method(as.data.frame.data.frame)

## function (x, row.names = NULL, ...) 
## {
##     cl <- oldClass(x)
##     i <- match("data.frame", cl)
##     if (i > 1L) 
##         class(x) <- cl[-(1L:(i - 1L))]
##     if (!is.null(row.names)) {
##         nr <- .row_names_info(x, 2L)
##         if (length(row.names) == nr) 
##             attr(x, "row.names") <- row.names
##         else stop(sprintf(ngettext(nr, "invalid 'row.names', length %d for a data frame with %d row", 
##             "invalid 'row.names', length %d for a data frame with %d rows"), 
##             length(row.names), nr), domain = NA)
##     }
##     x
## }
## <bytecode: 0x000001e57b5ee0a8>
## <environment: namespace:base>
```

It looks like `as.data.frame.tbl_df()` does not use `row.names`. Whereas, `as.data.frame.data.frame()` use it to set attribute `row.names` of the output dataframe.

I do not believe that it would be a bug in R. So, I am looking for an explanation. However, this is the extent of my investigative ability in R. Any help is most welcome.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking here. As you state yourself: *"It looks like as.data.frame.tbl_df() does not use row.names"*. So supplying a `row.names` argument to `as.data.frame` acting on a `tibble` simply gets ignored (as it gets captured in the `...`). What more are you looking for?

Comment: Although `tibble` highly discourage use of rownames, it does allow it. `as_tibble()` has `rownames` argument which can take `NA` to keep this attribute. I am unsure why this argument is not being used. [Help](https://rdrr.io/r/base/as.data.frame.html) says that `x` can be any R object and `row.names` can be a `character` vector. My observation does not seem to match with these statements and thus I am confused.

Comment: The discussion about the use of rownames aside (as you probably know, `dplyr` does offer a `column_to_rownames()` function), I still don't understand the confusion. The argument `row.names` gets ignored in `as.data.frame.tbl_df()`, by design. That's all there is to it. It doesn't throw an error or warning, because it gets absorbed in the `...` argument. You have the ellipsis because that's how the generic `as.data.frame` was defined.

Comment: The question of "why" is one that only the `tibble` package authors can answer. I would recommend opening an issue in their GitHub repo: https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues.

Comment: @MauritsEvers: Yes, I know about `column_to_rownames()`. I don't even use `rownames` !! But, Yes, you are right. It looks like a design choice and as suggested by @Mikko maybe the GitHub would be better forum for this question. Thank You for your time :)

Comment: @MikkoMarttila: I was just looking at that page :) I think you are right, GitHub might be better forum for this one. Thank You for your time :)

Comment: @Shivam7898 No worries & good luck.